# How to get the biggest id of database in SQL?

Tags: sql, mariadb, max

How can I get the greatest id between all my database tables?

Intuitively something like this, but doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(n.id_order, s.id_order, pr.id_order, pu.id_order) 
FROM 
    neworders AS n, salesorders AS s, proposalspurchase AS pr, purchaseorders AS pu
```

I need help with this id_order, is possible get each id easily and compare them to get the max. But is possible do it with just one query?

Comment: first which database system are you using, second JOIN 's are around for thirty years now, you should start using them

Comment: 1)mariaDB, 2) I'm obviously much younger than 30

Comment: *I'm obviously much younger than 30* - then why didn't you learn it **properly** from the get go?? What fall back on a technique that's been discouraged for 30+ years?

Comment: but what do I know if it's a good technique or not, evidently in Italy they don't teach us anything, I wrote it like this without a join so as not to waste time. Why do I keep getting useless comments? answer if you know how to do otherwise don't waste time for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need help with this id_order, is possible get each id easily and
> compare them to get the max. But is possible do it with just one query

Yes, We can get all ids and compare them to get the max using union or union all.

```
select MAX(id_order) as greatest_id
from (
    select MAX(id_order) as id_order from neworders
    union all
    select MAX(id_order) as id_order from salesorders
    union all
    select MAX(id_order) as id_order from proposalspurchase
    union all
    select MAX(id_order) as id_order from purchaseorders
) as orders;
```

Comment: thanks, i get the result with this caveat: Current selection does not contain a unique field. Edit grid, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete may not be available.                                     
But running the query from java doesn't seem to be a problem! :)

Comment: Yes, this scans each table just once so it is more efficient. It might also be better to pre-aggregate in each select, like `select max(id_order) from neworders union all select max(id_order) from sales_order...`.

Comment: @GMB; I appreciate the advise.
I have updated the answer right away. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

you can use [GRETEAST][1]

Please use alwaxs JOIN as comma makes a CFROS JOINn which makes a lot more rows as resultset

```
SELECT 
    GREATEST(IFNULL(MAX(n.id_order),0), IFNULL(MAX(s.id_order),0), IFNULL(MAX(pr.id_order),0), IFNULL(MAX(pu.id_order),0)) 
FROM 
    neworders AS n, salesorders AS s, proposalspurchase AS pr, purchaseorders AS pu
```

or better to adreess all commends

```
SELECT GREATEST( IFNULL(n.id,0),IFNULL(s.id,0),IFNULL(pr.id,0),IFNULL(pu.id,0))
  FROM
(SELECT MAX(neworders .id_order) id FROM neworders ) n 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(salesorders.id_order) id FROM salesorders ) s
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(proposalspurchase.id_order) id FROM proposalspurchase ) p3 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(purchaseorders.id_order) id FROM purchaseorders ) pu
```

SAMPLE

```
CREATE TABLe t1(id int)
```

```
CREATE TABLe t2(id int)
```

```
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
```

> ```
> Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
CREATE TABLe t3(id int)
```

```
INSERT INTO t3 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(5)
```

> ```
> Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
CREATE TABLe t4(id int)
```

```
INSERT INTO t4 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(8)
```

> ```
> Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT  GREATEST(IFNULL(MAX(t1.id),0), IFNULL(MAX(t2.id),0), IFNULL(MAX(t3.id),0), IFNULL(MAX(t4.id),0)) 
  FROM t1 CROSS JOIN t2 CROSS JOIN t3 CROSS JOIN t4
```

| GREATEST(IFNULL(MAX(t1.id),0), IFNULL(MAX(t2.id),0), IFNULL(MAX(t3.id),0), IFNULL(MAX(t4.id),0)) |
| --- |
| 0 |

```
SELECT GREATEST( IFNULL(t1.id,0),IFNULL(t2.id,0),IFNULL(t3.id,0),IFNULL(t4.id,0))
  FROM
(SELECT MAX(t1.id) id FROM t1) t1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(t2.id) id FROM t2) t2 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(t3.id) id FROM t3) t3 CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(t4.id) id FROM t4) t4
```

| GREATEST( IFNULL(t1.id,0),IFNULL(t2.id,0),IFNULL(t3.id,0),IFNULL(t4.id,0)) |
| --- |
| 8 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6gqXbkmU)

Comment: but unfortunately it return an empty set

Comment: can you add tables and data https://dbfiddle.uk/zPM4LGDi to reproduce the problem

Comment: @Matte i add an example how it wkrs, but it will not be fast

Comment: i couldn't do it with four tables however another user solved the problem, thanks

Comment: this works also with 4 tables https://dbfiddle.uk/8cFr2Qcw

Comment: This works, but returns an empty set if *any of the tables* is empty. Also, the cartesian join generates many more rows than what is actually needed to produce the expected result, so this will become inefficient if the tables are big.